# consultar sql server desde un form con PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

buen dia, realizo consultas a xampp con php de una manera muy facil, el problema es que hay más información en otra BD que es Sql Server y la verdad no se absolutamente nada de consultas para eso, podrían ayudarme en decirme como hacer una consulta?
al xampp me conecto de una manera facil y al buscar el codigo tambien es sencillo ya se los muestro (al presionar el boton buscar en el Form junto con JS ejecuta este codigo(el input se llama OP donde ingreso el numero))...

```php
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','BD')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

$OP=$_POST['OP'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE OP='$OP'";
$execute= mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
$data=array();

foreach($execute as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Para la parte de JS que se ejecuta con el boton "buscar" este es el codigo..

```js
let btn_buscar22 = document.getElementById('btn-buscar22');

btn_buscar22.addEventListener('click', async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    try {

        let frm = document.getElementById('frm-busqueda');

        let solictud = await fetch('guardado/buscar.php',{
            method:'post',
            body: new FormData(frm)
        })

        let respuesta = await solictud.json();
        console.log(respuesta)
    document.getElementById('d-fecha').value =respuesta[0].fecha
    document.getElementById('d-cliente').value =respuesta[0].cliente
 


  

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Con ese codigo busco la información en xampp la cual esta ligada a la misma "OP" y aparece todo lo que busco pero el problema es que en sql server solo he logrado conectarme pero no se de que manera realizar las búsquedas allá...

```php
<?php

$conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=192....;database=MYDATABASE","USER","PASS");

?>
```

Comment: Cuando mencionas "información en otra BD" te refieres a otra BD o a otra tabla diferente que se encuentra en la misma BD. En caso que te refieras a la primera opción, no hay manera posible, pero si es una tabla que se aloja en la misma BD que estás usando entonces puedes usar un JOIN entre tablas, siempre y cuando ambas tablas tengan una columna relacional con una clave foránea. Un saludo

Comment: La info está en otra base de datos (BD1) la cual es "Sql Server" que es la que estoy intentando consultar. Y las consultas que yo hago es en un xampp que sería otra (BD2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el código que muestras, ya estableciste conexión a la base de datos. Sobre esta conexión, puedes lanzar una consulta SQL para obtener la información que buscas, por ejemplo, algo equivalente a lo que haces contra mySQL sería más o menos así:

```
<?php
  $conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=192....;database=MYDATABASE","USER","PASS");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE OP=?";
  $sth = $conexion.prepare($query);
  $sth.execute([$OP]);
  $op = $sth.fetchAll();
  echo json_encode($op);
?>
```

OJO, que estoy utilizando una consulta parametrizada, con lo cual evitamos ser vulnerables a inyección SQL y, por tanto, es *mejor* aún que lo que haces con mySQL en el ejemplo de tu pregunta.

Encontrarás más información y ejemplos en la documentación oficial:

- [Objetos de Datos PHP (PHP Data Objects-PDO)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)
- [Clase PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php)
- [PDO::prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)
- [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)